# Cannot read property 'style' of null in three places

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

When I run my code it give me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at onlyShowInput1H (/:673:42) at showInputH (/:995:9) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:85:117

In more detail here is what code does:

user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 1st div user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 2nd div (stored in localStorage)
user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 3nd div(stored in localStorage)
A do list is displayed with all the inputs the user inputed(stored in localStorage)
This error is being displayed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at /script.js:66:5 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at onlyShowInput1H (/ITHB.js:457:42) at showInputH (/ITHB.js:779:9) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:85:104)

I think the second error is affecting my code, from saving the 21st input because it's not reading it

Here is a link to a plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/HbT4WKFpqQrW5Ikv?open=lib%2Fscript.js

And here is a code snippet (not of my entire code but the part that isn't working):

```js
function showInputHText() {
  document.getElementById("inputHText").style.display = "block";
}


/* START of show input functions */
/* START: hard show input functions */
function dontShowInput1H() {
  document.getElementById("hard-block").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput1H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo22").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo23").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo24").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo25").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo26").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput2H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo23").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo24").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo25").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo26").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput3H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo24").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo25").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo26").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";

}

function onlyShowInput4H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo25").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo26").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";

}

function onlyShowInput5H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo26").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";


}

function onlyShowInput6H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo27").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";

}

function onlyShowInput7H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo28").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput8H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo29").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput9H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDo30").style.display = "none";
}

function onlyShowInput10H() {
  document.getElementById("data21").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data22").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data23").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data24").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data25").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data26").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data27").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data28").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data29").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("data30").style.display = "block";
}


/*START show save btns*/

function showSaveE() {
  document.getElementById("saveE").style.display = "block";
}

function showSaveM() {
  document.getElementById("saveM").style.display = "block";
}

function showSaveH() {
  document.getElementById("saveH").style.display = "block";
}

/*END of show btns*/


/* START: function show input easy*/

function showInputE() {
  var numEAI = document.getElementById('numEAI');
  if (numEAI.value == 0) {
    alert("If you don't have any, click I don't have any easy assignments today");
  } else if (numEAI.value == 1) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput1();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 2) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput2();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 3) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput3();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 4) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput4();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 5) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput5();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 6) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput6();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 7) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput7();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 8) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput8();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 9) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput9();
  } else if (numEAI.value == 10) {
    showSaveE();
    onlyShowInput10();
  } else {
    alert("Try doing between 1-10 easy assignments OR click I dont have any easy assignments today if you dont have any");
  }

}
/* START: function show input medium*/
function showInputM() {
  var numMAI = document.getElementById('numMAI');
  if (numMAI.value == 0) {
    alert("If you don't have any, click I don't have any medium assignments");
  } else if (numMAI.value == 1) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput1M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 2) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput2M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 3) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput3M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 4) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput4M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 5) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput5M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 6) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput6M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 7) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput7M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 8) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput8M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 9) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput9M();
  } else if (numMAI.value == 10) {
    showSaveM();
    onlyShowInput10M();
  } else {
    alert("Try doing 1-10 medium assuignments OR click I dont have any medium assignments today if you dont have any");
  }

}


/* START: function show input hard*/
function showInputH() {
  var numHAI = document.getElementById('numHAI');
  if (numHAI.value == 0) {
    alert("If you don't have any, click I don't have any hard assignents");
  } else if (numHAI.value == 1) {
    onlyShowInput1H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 2) {
    onlyShowInput2H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 3) {
    onlyShowInput3H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 4) {
    onlyShowInput4H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 5) {
    onlyShowInput5H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 6) {
    onlyShowInput6H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 7) {
    onlyShowInput7H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 8) {
    onlyShowInput8H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 9) {
    onlyShowInput9H();
    showSaveH();
  } else if (numHAI.value == 10) {
    onlyShowInput10H();
    showSaveH();
  } else {
    alert("Try doing between 1-10 hard assignments OR click I dont have any hard assignments today if you dont have any");
  }
}



/* display functions in form */
function displayM() {
  document.getElementById("easyAssignments").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mediumAssignments").style.display = "block";
}

function displayH() {
  document.getElementById("mediumAssignments").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("hardAssignments").style.display = "block";
}

function displayTDL() {
  document.getElementById("hardAssignments").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toDoList").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To Do List</title>

  <!--JS Files-->
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
  <form id="ui">
    <fieldset>
      <!--Start of Form-->

      <div id="hardAssignments">
        <p>How many hard tasks do you have to do today?</p>

        <input class="pink" min="0" max="10" type="number" id="numHAI" required>

        <p></p>
        <script src="ITHB.js"></script>

        <button style="display:block" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showInputHText(); showInputH();">Enter</button>
        <p style="display:none;" id="inputHText">List your hard tasks here (then click save)</p>

        <input class="red" style="display:none" id='data21' name='data21'>

        <input id="saveH" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="displayTDL()" />


        <p>or</p>
        <button value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="dontShowInput1H();
      displayTDL();">
     I don't have any hard tasks today
  </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      <center>
        <!--End of Form-->

<!--Start of To-do List-->

        <div text-align="center" id=toDoList style="display:none">
          <h1>To Do List:</h1>

          <h3>Hard Tasks:</h3>
          <p>All your hard tasks for the day</p>

          <input type="checkbox" style="font-size: 30px;" id="toDo21" name="toDo21" value="toDo21" />
          <label style="font-size: 30px;" class="strikethrough" for="toDo21"><output id='out21' for="data21"></output></label><br>

    </fieldset>
  </form>

  </div>

  <script src="ITHB.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>


  <!--End of To-do List-->

  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So that means it could not find the element with that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error: You are missing name="btn" on line 26 of index.html

```
<button name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showInputEText(); showInputE();">Enter</button>
```

Second error: You have two typos on line 50 and 51 of script.js, ou should be out.

```
var out15 = ui.out15;
```

Third error: You have are trying to get a lot of elements that dont exist in your html (data22 - data30).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed these blunders and now it works!